# Fun + Challenging =?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that can be used to describe an activity (e.g., work or studies) that is both “fun” and “challenging”. Words I have tried include “intriguing”, “fascinating”, “engaging”, “captivating” and “absorbing”, but I feel that these all are slightly off the mark, usually because while they *might* describe an activity that is both “fun” and “challenging”, they *don't necessarily* do so in my eyes/ears.

However, as English is not my first language, I might very well be incorrect. Is there are word that conveys the meaning of “fun” and “interesting”, and if so, which word?

Comment: Part of the difficulty in this question may lie in the dichotomy between *fun,* which denotes amusement and diversion (its origin lies in a 16th C word for foolishness - cf. dictionary.reference.com) and *challenging,* which could be just the opposite.  If we offer people something that's *fun and challenging* it's like mixing *"salty"* and *"sweet"* - a tasty combination, to be sure, but nothing like the one-word *"umami"*.  I think the concept comes across in the two words.

Comment: Puzzling means difficult to solve, which for some is also fun.

Comment: @cheflo The ones you have given are great. I'd add "stimulating," "thrilling," "exciting," "inspiring," "beautiful," "prepossessing," "ennobling," "engrossing," and (least interestingly) "interesting." But you're right; we need a better word for this most relevant concept to human existence.

Answer (score 2):

[**fulfilling**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fulfilling+definition)

Google definition:

> adjective
>
> making someone **satisfied or happy** because of **fully developing** their character or abilities.

"fully developing" one's character or ability is not an easy task for most, so it's not really a far cry from challenging.

When someone describes their work as fulfilling, I take it to
mean that their work is challenging but very enjoyable because it suits their interests.

Comment: Interesting suggestion! My original intent was to describe the activity as "fulfilling, fun and challenging", and I was looking to abbreviate it to two words. Your comment made me realize that maybe "fulfilling" encompasses all those adjectives and I can be content with one word at this stage. 

However, I don't think it is a good word to convey that something is "fun and challenging", as it is not restricted to only those two properties.

Answer (score 0):

The word rewarding comes to mind..perhaps not exactly what you are looking for, but encompasses both words to some degree in my opinion.